# Field validation in RadListView

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

When I validate my fields in `RadListView`, I'd like to be able to present a message to the user about validation errors. Using [this example project](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=Q0J9Ft&v=12), I get either overlaps or gaps in the list as the resizing of the items isn't reflected. If I call `.refresh()` on the `RadListView` as has been suggested in other answers, it removes my `TextField` focus.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a way to tackle this in nativescript-angular?

[image: validation overlap]

Comment: ListView template should be static, dynamic templates (using ngIf) might not be a good idea. Try using two different templates, one for valid items and another for invalid items. If you are going to update the validation status after the list item is rendered, you might have to force refresh the list item to sync with new template.

Comment: @Manoj Refreshing the list as a user is typing is problematic because the `TextField` is ripped out from under them. I want to do immediate validation, not on form submit. Whether I use `ngIf` or `[visibility]..`, the height of the control simply doesn't update unless I call `refresh()`. How can I get immediate feedback while maintaining field focus?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Realtime updates could be difficult on ListView. Though it's possible to update one list item alone without refreshing the whole ListView, it might not work for you as the TextField could be rendered again and loose focus. Why don't you try a floating tooltip kind of layout that could be shown right below the active list item on the screen, of course it's a bit different design but might solve your issue efficiently.